# CMD - Using spaces in an input to set /p

Tags: cmd

All right so I'm trying to make a chat program and well basically if I type anything with a space into a set /p command it will just close the window.
CODE:
chatroom

```
echo User: %account%
echo Chatting with: %sndaccount%
echo.
set /p output=<data/%sndaccount%_input.txt
echo Receive: %output%
set /p input=Send: 
echo "%input%">data/%account%_input.txt


if %input%==!exit (
cls
echo available>data/%account%check.txt
exit
)
cls
goto chatroom
```

If I type anything with a space EX: Hello World  into the `set /p input=Send:` command it will just close the window (crash).

What should I do to prevent it from crashing ???

Comment: Please add your code to the question (just click on the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35706227/edit) link at the bottom), without that it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Try `if "%input%"=="!exit" (`. Read and follow [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php).